# JavaScript sql result row, using a property that has parenthesis in its name

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, attributes

I am trying to do nested queries in order to insert into a table based apon an earlier select statement. However I am running into trouble because my first select statement selects and AVG() of a row. I have not been able to find a way to get the result row object that I have to select the property 'AVG(row)' instead of the trying to call .AVG() on something. The code is below and any help would be appreciated.

```
var sql1 = 'SELECT tropename, AVG(criticScore) FROM tropesWithScore where tropeName = '+ '\'' + trope + '\'';
            //console.log(sql1)
            con.query(sql1, function (err1, result1) {
                if (err1) throw err1;
                Object.keys(result1).forEach(function(key) {
                    var row2 = result1[key];
                    var trope2 = row.tropeName;
                    console.log(trope2)
                    var avgScore = row.AVG(criticScore)
                    console.log(avgScore)
                    sql = 'INSERT INTO TropesWithAverageScores (tropeName, criticScore) VALUES (' + trope2 + ',' + '\'' + avgScore + ')';
                    ///console.log(sql)
                    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {}
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself,

first, I was getting the attribute on row, not row2 object.

Secondly I simplified it by aliasing my first select state, so it now reads

```
SELECT tropename, AVG(criticScore) as avgCS FROM tropesWithScore where tropeName = '+ '\'' + trope + '\'';
```

Hope this helps someone else!